# Calculating group area percentages in ArcGIS Pro using Summarize Within

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, area, spatial-statistics, vector-grid

I have a grid (vector file) in ArcGIS Pro, and I want to calculate the percentages of the area of different anthrome types in another vector file (Anthromes 12K DGG Dataverse) for each grid cell. I used the tool Summarize Within to calculate the percentages of each anthrome type per grid cell (Add group percentages).

Now I am faced with another question: does the tool calculate the percentage of total area of a certain anthrome type OR only the percentage of occurrences of a certain anthrome type (i.e. in how many polygons it occurs inside a grid cell vs the total number of polygons inside the same cell). In the resulting table there is a column named  Percent of area, but I am still not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The total geographic area of each type is considered.

If you wanted to check, you can Intersect your grid with the anthrome layer and recalculate the area, then represent that by a percent. Summation of each percent should give you the same answer as your summarization table.